# Select <li> elements in a <ul> popup using arrow keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-lists

I have a chat application where the user can issue slash commands from the chat input bar. Several chat applications do something similar, but Slack is a well known example.

Currently, the user can enter either `/` or `.` and a popup will show above the input bar, showing all available commands. This popup is essentially a `<div>` with an `<ul>`. The `<li>` items are populated via an api call. The user can then select a command by clicking on the `<li>` item.

I would like to be able to go through and select a command using the up/down arrow keys. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use React's `SyntheticEvent`s to listen for keyboard input.
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#keyboard-events

Assuming you are getting an array of options from the API, you can traverse that array when you hit the up/down arrows and maintain a cursor with the position in your component's state.

In the render method, you can then add a class to show the active item based on the cursor on your array.